# when i create a table in hive i get null in the map field

Tags: json, dictionary, null, hive

I create a table in hive from a json file with this structure:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "clave": "1",
    "tipo_registro": "Planilla",
    "creado_por": "ETL cargaInicialPlanilla",
    "fecha_creacion": "2016-09-269T00:00:00.0Z",
    "modificado_por": "ETL cargaInicialPlanilla",
    "fecha_ultima_modificacion": "2016-09-269T00:00:00.0Z",
    "oficina": "comun",
    "valores": {
        "P_ACTIVO": "1",
        "P_AT_ACTIVO": "1",
        "P_AT_DESCRIPCION": "Fecha de Emisión",
        "P_AT_EDITABLE": "1",
        "P_AT_IDTIPODATO": "5",
        "P_AT_LARGO": "0",
        "P_AT_REPETIBLE": "0",
        "P_AT_TD_ACTIVO": "1",
        "P_AT_TD_DESCRIPCION": "System.DateTime",
        "P_AT_TD_VALOR": "System.DateTime",
        "P_IDATRIBUTOM": "15",
        "P_IDPLANILLAM": "1",
        "P_IDRECAUDO": "11",
        "P_OCULTO": "0",
        "P_ORDEN": "1"
    }
}
```

i put the file inside HDFS (/user/hive/TestTable) And create the table with this command:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test
(
id STRING,
clave STRING,
tipo_registro STRING,
creado_por STRING,
fecha_creacion STRING,
modificado_por STRING,
fecha_ultima_modificacion STRING,
oficina STRING,
valor MAP<String, String>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION  '/user/hive/TestTable';
```

But when i query the table, my valor or map field is always null.

I see other posts about this, but in most of them, always use struct instead of map and i need to use map, because that field is not static and could have different fields in other documents.

I'll appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you tell me how are you trying to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Json has valores but in your hive table you defined as valor , this is the reason it is always null , change it to valores in your hive table to match your json attribute name ,it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, it was that. It was a silly mistake. I thought that the names of the table were not important. Thanks.